# Powershell - How to use "remove-item" with multiple selectors and wildcards?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a folder called "test-folder" which contains alot of files with different types. I want to delete all music files. (mp3, mp4, mpeg ...)

I know i can delete all mp3 files like this:

`remove-item C:\path\to\test-folder\"*.mp3*"`

Is it possible to add multiple wildcard selectors e.g.:

`remove-item C:\path\to\test-folder\"*.mp3*+*.mpeg*"`

so i can delete all the music files with one command?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For a single directory:

```
remove-item C:\path\to\test-folder\* -include *.mp3, *.mpeg
```

or a useful method for when files span multiple directories:

```
remove-item C:\path\to\test-folder\*.mp3, C:\path\to\other\test-folder\*.mpeg
```

or you could move to that directory first:

```
cd C:\path\to\test-folder\
remove-item *.mp3, *.mpeg
```

Use `Get-Help Remove-Item -full` for full details of available flags and usage.

Comment: Thanks for the info about `Get-Help`.

Answer (score 0):

```
remove-item C:\path\to\test\folder\* -include .mp4,.mp3
```

The above command needs to changed a little to work correctly (courtesy @root)

```
remove-item C:\path\to\test\folder\* -include *.mp4,*.mp3
```

Comment: Close, but I believe you would need the wildcard in front of the extensions.

Comment: Well to be honest I cannot test this right now so I am not going to doubt you but I would also like to point out that I think the one wildcard character that I already have in the path would do the trick, again you might be totally correct.

Comment: It actually needs both - the asterisk at the end of the file path and at the beginning of each extension delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

For the opposite case, I want to remove all of the ArtWork, db, Zune, desktop files from the Music folders.  We need to use -Recurse for network drive NAS1:

```
\\NAS1\Public> remove-item '.\Shared Music\*' -include desktop.ini,_msl.db,Zune*.jpg,Folder.jpg,AlbumArt*.jpg -Recurse
```